# shell script for automated git svn rebase, push to github

Tags: git, shell

I'm trying to set up a shell script (eventually to be run as a cron job) to automatically do a `git svn rebase` and then push the results to a github repository. Here's what I have now:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=/sw/bin:$PATH
cd ~/Projects/FieldTrip

git checkout svnMirror
git svn rebase
git push github svnMirror
git checkout master
git merge svnMirror
```

The problem is, it performs the checkout and rebase, but it doesn't any of the steps after those ones:

```
$ fieldtrip_rebase.sh 
Switched to branch 'svnMirror'
Current branch svnMirror is up to date.
Everything up-to-date
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'github/master' by 7 commits.
Already up-to-date.
```

Any idea why that may be?

Comment: The trace indicates that it does all the steps, but there is nothing to be done in the later steps - or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @john - No, the line `Your branch is ahead of 'github/master' by 7 commits` indicates that the `git push github svnMirror` should be pushing something, but it doesn't actually execute the push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us follow the steps and output:

```
git checkout svnMirror
```

you got `Switched to branch 'svnMirror'` - Good

```
git svn rebase
```

you got `Current branch svnMirror is up to date.` - Good

```
git push github svnMirror
```

you got `Everything up-to-date` - Good. So you had nothing to push. Then it continues...

```
git checkout master
```

you got `Switched to branch 'master'.Your branch is ahead of 'github/master' by 7 commits.`

```
git merge svnMirror
```

you got `Already up-to-date.` There is nothing to merge from svnMirror branch.

It has done all that you wanted it to do. Note, it is master that is ahead of github/master by 7 commits and you are not pushing it.